# Auto-populating first column in an HTML table with the first date of actual months

Tags: php, mysql

For the code below, `$count++` prints out rows of numbers ascending from 1 on up.

How could I replace it with monthly intervals starting with September 1, 2010 6 am eastern?  (I. e. row one has September 1, 2010, row 2 has October 1, 2010, etc.?)

I would like the dates to be in a format that would allow me to compare to timestamps from MySQL

```
$result = mysql_query($sqlStr3);
$count = 1;  
$arr = array();
echo "<table>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

            echo '<tr >';
            echo '<td >'.$count++.'</td>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a fan of the [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function. It takes a readable string and converts it into a Unix timestamp, and it handles relative time really well as well.

First, create a variable with your initial date:

```
$date = strtotime("September 1, 2010");
```

Each month in the loop is created by simply adding one month to the variable:

```
$date = strtotime("+1 month", $date);
```

You can use [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format the timestamp to output it in your list:

```
echo date("F j, Y", $date);
```

You can see the full range of formats [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Alternately, if you're using PHP 5.3, you can take full advantage of [the DateTime object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) (introduced in 5.2, but things like `DateTime::add()` didn't exist until 5.3).

As far as compatibility with MySQL, you can either use the MySQL function [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to return a Unix timestamp from your query, or run the MySQL timestamp through `strtotime()` as well to convert it to a Unix timestamp.

Comment: @John The date function, which formats the date, goes inside the column - i.e `echo "<td>" . date("F j, Y", $date) . "</td>"`

Comment: When I do that, every row has the same date... how do I get them to ascend?

Comment: @John The line `$date = strtotime("+1 month", $date);` is your iterator. You use it instead of `$count++`. It says "take the existing `$date` timestamp, and return a value equal to midnight on the first of the next calendar month. Just put it anywhere inside your loop.